# Evaluate $\sum_{i=1}^nF^k_{p_i}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $F_{p_n}$ denote the $p_n$-th Fibonacci Number where $p_n$ is $n$-th prime. Now define,

> $$\mathfrak{S}_k=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^nF^k_{p_i}$$

Is there any formula for $\mathfrak{S}_k$? I tried to find a recursive relation but couldn't. Even $\mathfrak{S}_1$ seems difficult to evaluate. Can anyone help?

Comment: There is no known formula even for $p_n$... Would you be content with an asymptotic formula?

Comment: @ajotatxe: That will be good.

Comment: As far as asymptotic growth, we know that $p_i\approx i (\log i +\log\log i-1)$ and $F_n=[\phi^n/\sqrt{5}]$, from which you can get some approximate bounds for your series. For example, $F_{p_i}\approx \phi^{i\log(i)}/\sqrt{5}$, and from here you can do an integral approximation.